# Neutrino appearance and disappearance experiments

Tags: neutrinos

Why in neutrinos appearance experiments the background is said to be small? and how is it connected to the mixing angles? Why is it opposite in the neutrino disappearance experiments?

Comment: can you give links for these experimenta?

Comment: Actually I got these concept from a neutrino physics book by Kim ,Guinti.

Comment: found it, I think. Do you have a page for the concept of "appearance and disappearance experiments" http://theor.jinr.ru/~vnaumov/Eng/JINR_Lectures/books/Giunti2007.pdf

Comment: ok, it is oscillations on page 261

Comment: yes ,it is on page 261. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Sorry,  allthough I can handwave some answer, I would have to read the chapter details  in order to write a correct one.